# Does a closed form exist for the following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Initially this integral looked familiar but soon I noticed the $x^2$. I tried to solve it however I could before quickly (albeit very quickly) moving onto online solvers and Mathematica.

The online solves can't give a solution and Mathematica also doesn't.

Here:$$\frac{1}{2\pi\beta}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}e^{ikx}\sin(\beta tk^2)dk$$

Comment: Can you find the Fourier transform of $\sin (x^2)$? If so, you could try differentiating by $t$.

Comment: Mathematica can give solution try: `FourierTransform[1/(2 Pi \[Beta])*Sin[\[Beta] t k^2]/k^2, k, x, 
 FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope you're well!

Using differentiation under the integral sign, one can parametrize the given integral as
$$
I(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi\beta}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2}\sin\left(a\beta tk^2\right) \mathrm{d}k \Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}I(a)}{\mathrm{d}a} = \frac{t}{2\pi} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{ikx}\cos\left(a\beta tk^2\right) \mathrm{d}k.
$$

Since $\cos\alpha = (e^{i\alpha} + e^{-i\alpha})/2$, we can split the derivative into two integrals:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}I(a)}{\mathrm{d}a} = \frac{t}{4\pi}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \left[e^{ik(x+a\beta tk)} + e^{ik(x-a\beta tk)}\right] \mathrm{d}k.
$$

Complete the square of both exponents. Notice that
$$
\exp\left[ik(x\pm a\beta tk)\right] = \exp\left[\pm i\left(\sqrt{a\beta t}k \pm \frac{x}{2\sqrt{a\beta t}}\right)^2\right]\exp\left(\mp i\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right).
$$
Taking $s = \sqrt{a\beta t}k \pm x/2\sqrt{a\beta t}$ respectively, we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{ik(x+a\beta tk)} \mathrm{d} k &= \frac{\exp\left(- i\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right)}{\sqrt{a\beta t}} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{is^2}\mathrm{d}s = \frac{\exp\left(- i\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right)}{\sqrt{a\beta t}} (1+i)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}, \\
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{ik(x-a\beta tk)} \mathrm{d} k &= \frac{\exp\left( i\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right)}{\sqrt{a\beta t}} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-is^2}\mathrm{d}s = \frac{\exp\left(i\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right)}{\sqrt{a\beta t}} (1-i)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}I(a)}{\mathrm{d}a} &= \frac{t}{4\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a\beta t}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[(1+i)\exp\left(- i\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right) + (1-i)\exp\left(i\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{t}{a\beta}}\left(\cos\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t} + \sin\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, we integrate with respect to $a$. Following the output of [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28cos%28k%2Fx%29+%2B+sin%28k%2Fx%29%29%2Fsqrt%7Bx%7D),
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{t}{\beta}} \left[ \sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4\beta t}} \left( \mathcal{S}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x^2}{4\pi a\beta t}}\right) - \mathcal{C}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x^2}{4\pi a\beta t}}\right) \right) + \sqrt{a}\left(\cos\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t} + \sin\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right) \right] + C \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{t}{\beta}} \left[ \sqrt{\frac{\pi x^2}{2\beta t}} \left( \mathcal{S}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2\pi a\beta t}}\right) - \mathcal{C}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2\pi a\beta t}}\right) \right) + \sqrt{a}\left(\cos\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t} + \sin\frac{x^2}{4a\beta t}\right) \right] + C,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathcal{C}(x)$ and $\mathcal{S}(x)$ are the cosine and sine Fresnel integrals defined as
$$
\mathcal{C}(x) = \int^x_0 \cos\frac{\pi t^2}{2} \mathrm{d}t, \qquad
\mathcal{S}(x) = \int^x_0 \sin\frac{\pi t^2}{2} \mathrm{d}t.
$$

Notice that $I(a=0) = 0$ is satisfied only if $C = 0$ since
$$
\int^{+\infty}_0 \cos\frac{\pi t^2}{2} \mathrm{d}t = \int^{+\infty}_0 \sin\frac{\pi t^2}{2} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Therefore, we can retrieve the desired integral setting $a=1$:
$$
I(a=1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{t}{\beta}} \left[ \sqrt{\frac{\pi x^2}{2\beta t}} \left( \mathcal{S}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2\pi \beta t}}\right) - \mathcal{C}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2\pi \beta t}}\right) \right) + \cos\frac{x^2}{4\beta t} + \sin\frac{x^2}{4\beta t} \right].
$$

For $(x, \beta, t) = (0, 1, 1)$, the result works as [expected](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20sin%28x%5E2%29%2F%282%20pi%20x%5E2%29%20from%20x%3D-%E2%88%9E%20to%20x%3D%E2%88%9E). I have also checked the $(1, 1, 1)$ case. Hope you like it!

Comment: You are missing some parentheses for the Fresnel integrals.

Comment: Corrected! @Gary